# merge columns with same header name

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have two dfs:
df1=

```
index      colx      coly      colz
  0         45        35        54
```

df2=

```
index      colz      colx      colg      colf
  0         11        22        10         5
```

I want df1 to be:

```
index      colx      coly      colz      colf  
  0         45        35        54       nan
  1         22        nan       11        5
```

I was looking into merge and join, but I don't seem to be able to do it correctly

Thank you

Comment: are you talking about pandas? if so, please add pandas as one tag, then share the codes what you have tried so far.

Comment: There is no `coly` in the second dataframe, why do you have it in the output?

Comment: Thank you @DYZ. It is because I missed adding colf in the results. I will correct it now.

Comment: What happened to `colg` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can join the transposed dataframes, transpose the result again, and add a default numeric index:

```
df1.T.join(df2.T, rsuffix='r').T.reset_index(drop=True)
#       colx  coly  colz
#0      45.0  35.0  54.0
#1      22.0   NaN  11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df, df2], sort=False)[df.set_index('index').columns].reset_index(drop=True)

    colx    coly    colz
0   45      35.0    54
1   22      NaN     11
```

#### Using `pd.merge`

```
pd.merge(df,df2, how='outer')[df.set_index('index').columns]

    colx    coly    colz
0   45      35.0    54
1   22      NaN     11
```